# Making NullSpace give correct result for all parameters

Tags: linear-algebra

I found out that `NullSpace` only gives the correct answer for 'generic' parameters. For example,

```
NullSpace[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

gives `{}`, which is only correct for $ad-bc \neq 0$. I want to make that `NullSpace` always give the correct answer, by dividing cases if needed. How can I do this?

The specific example in my mind is the following $4\times4$ matrix

```
m = {{0, s, 1, 0}, {-s, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, -s}, {0, 1, s, 0}}
```

In general, the null space of `m` is empty, but for $s=\pm 1$, it has a nonzero null space. I want to compute the null space in those specific cases.

Comment: Indeed, the linear algebra functions are known to give generic results. With that said, ponder on the result of `Simplify[CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[{{0, s, 1, 0}, {-s, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, -s}, {0, 1, s, 0}}, x], x]]` and consider the conditions for the first component to be zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Reduce" can give the full solution space. With your example::

```
m = {{0, s, 1, 0}, {-s, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, -s}, {0, 1, s, 0}};
Reduce[m . {x1, x2, x3, x4} == 0, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The relations of interest can be found by augmenting with an identity, row reducing, and getting denominators from the augmented side. I show for this example.

```
mat = {{0, s, 1, 0}, {-s, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, -s}, {0, 1, s, 0}};
augmat = Join[mat, IdentityMatrix[Length[mat]], 2];
redmat = RowReduce[augmat];
relations = 
  Denominator[Flatten[redmat[[All, Length[mat[[1]]] + 1 ;;]]]];
relation = Apply[PolynomialLCM, relations]

(* Out[209]= -1 + s^2 *)
```

Comment: What is the mathematics behind this method? Why does it work?

Comment: The augmented part in effect records operations done in the process of row reducing the matrix. In particular, any divisions will appear as denominators in that part of the resulting matrix.

Comment: The solution states at the end that -1+s^2 should be not zero. However what can we say about intermediary steps in the row operations? If we find in an intermediary step that -2+s^2 should be not zero then this also counts or only the final result counts?

Comment: You won't lose denominators from intermediate steps. They remain as factors in the LCM of denoms in a given row.

Comment: If I want to get the most general solution I set ```mat = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}, {m, n, o, p}};``` and get for ```relation``` an expression identical to ```Det[mat]```.  However the solution for the case in the OP, i.e. ```mat = {{0, s, 1, 0}, {-s, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, -s}, {0, 1, s, 0}};``` is not identical to ```Det[mat]```. I do not understand why the general solution does not cover the special case.

Comment: It’s likely a factor of the determinant.

Comment: I’m traveling sans Mathematica right now.

Comment: Opened a new question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/290318/69288