# Nullspace if denominator is zero

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is based on a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/259599/69288) where the matrix

`mat = {{0, s, 1, 0}, {-s, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, -s}, {0, 1, s, 0}};`

is given and one wants to determine for which `s` there is only a trivial nullspace.

An [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259611/69288) was given by

```
mat = {{0, s, 1, 0}, {-s, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, -s}, {0, 1, s, 0}};
augmat = Join[mat, IdentityMatrix[Length[mat]], 2];
redmat = RowReduce[augmat];
relations = 
  Denominator[Flatten[redmat[[All, Length[mat[[1]]] + 1 ;;]]]];
relation = Apply[PolynomialLCM, relations]

(* Out[209]= -1 + s^2 *)
```

> The augmented part in effect records operations done in the process of row reducing the matrix. In particular, any divisions will appear as denominators in that part of the resulting matrix.

This means for s=1 and s=-1 there is only a trivial nullspace as the denominator is zero.

Now I generalize the above matrix by 16 variables

`mat = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}, {m, n, o, p}};`

and get as solution an expression that is identical to the determinant, i.e.

```
relation==Det[mat]
(*True*)
```

However, this identity does not hold for the initial matrix that contains only parameter `s`. There we find

```
relation^2==Det[mat]
(*True*)
```

The general solution should contain the special solution but it differs, $relation \ne relation^2$. How to explain this?

Comment: As I mentioned in the prior thread, the relation should divide the determinant.

Comment: How to determine the factor?

Comment: In this example your only factor is relation, which is of multiplicity 2.

Comment: But the general answer says that multiplicity is 1

Comment: When you plug specific values into the general form it might factor.

Comment: You seem to be looking for the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) of your matrix. Daniel has actually a resource function for that, cf. https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MatrixMinimalPolynomial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why do you just don't use `Inverse[mat]`? Like so:

```
mat = {{0, s, 1, 0}, {-s, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, -s}, {0, 1, s, 0}};
matinv = Denominator[Flatten[Inverse[mat]]];
relation = Apply[PolynomialLCM, matinv]
```

Now the answer: PolynomialLCM gives you the least common polynomial. If the determinant happens to factor into `det = poly * poly`, then it will just spit out poly. In the general case with `mat = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}, {m, n, o, p}};` with arbitrary coefficients this will just give you the determinant. In the special case, a further factorization is possible, so this is what PolynomialLCM is doing.